# Is there any chance to get access violation from memcpy, if src buffer is accessed(read/write) from other thread

Tags: c++, c

I got an access violation from my application.

CallStack:

```
0da0ccfc 77c46fa3 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xe 
0da0d004 4dfeee3a msvcrt!memcpy+0x33 
0da0d45c 4dfdbc4b MyLibrary!MyClass::MyFunc+0x8d [MyFile.cpp @ 574]

[MyFile.cpp @ 574 memcpy( m_pMyPointer, m_pSrcPointer, m_nDataSize);
```

Here Im sure the following things.. m_pMyPointer is valid and any other thread will not read or write to this memory. Size of m_pMyPointer is greater than m_nDataSize. m_pSrcPointer may accessible from other thread( read or write ) there is very little chance for the size of m_pSrcPointer as less than m_nDataSize.

My doubt is, is there any cahnce to get access violation from memcpy( m_pMyPointer, m_pSrcPointer, m_nDataSize), if any other thread tries to read/write to m_pSrcPointer. Since memcpy() reads m_pSrcPointer, and not write to it..

Comment: On which operating system? Did you enable warnings and debugging info at compilation time (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g` on Linux)? Did you use a leakage detector like `valgrind` from http://valgrind.org/ ?

Comment: Not really, unless that other thread is making m_pSrcPointer an invalid pointer.
Can you get a breakpoint where it crashes?

Comment: Operating system is Windows XP

Comment: Not really, unless that other thread is making m_pSrcPointer an invalid pointer. Can you get a breakpoint where it crashes? >> But I cant reproduce this issue.. I got it once. I suspect the reason is multiple threads accessing same buffer.

Comment: Well, where you say "there is very little chance ...". If that is not true (the size of the pointed to allocation is too small) you can certainly get an access violation.

Comment: Can you post some of the code?

Comment: `Size of m_pMyPointer is greater than m_nDataSize` doesn't make any sense in the context. What is this supposed to mean? Ditto for `size of m_pSrcPointer as less than m_nDataSize`.

Comment: As the existing answers say, the concurrent read/write shouldn't cause your program to crash.  If it's reproducible, you could add a proper mutex and see if it still crashes... that would definitely assure you that concurrent read/write is not the sole cause.

Answer (score 1):

I would exclude that. Concurrent read access to a memory area is by definition thread-safe. When one thread writes to a location of memory which is read by another, you lose thread-safety in the sense that result is unpredictable but you still should not get an access violation (in most sane platforms, including x86).

Most likely, the size of the *valid* memory area pointed by either `m_pMyPointer` or `m_pSrcPointer` is smaller than `m_nDataSize`.

However, if you have doubts that the same piece of memory is read and written to by different threads at the same time, it means you are at the very least missing a locking scheme there.

Comment: Concurrent read is Ok, But I suspect problem when write from other thread. What about a buffer write from other thread, and other thread tries to read from the same memory ?

Comment: That affects program correctness, but should not cause an exception. Edited the answer to explain that.

Comment: This is not necessarily true.  Most modern OSes allocate pages "on demand", so it is at least conceivable that a concurrent write and read to the same location, if the page is not already mapped, could cause a fault.  (Or at least, the multi-threading models of every modern OS allow it.)

Comment: @Nemo That is true for any access to memory, including code execution, and unless pages are explicitly locked in RAM. Still, it is invisible at the application level. The OS should transparently handle that. Here OP is using WinXP.

Comment: Those examples are concurrent reads, which as you know are not data races...  So a crash there would be an actual bug.  I suppose it is unlikely for the read and write cases to be very different, though.

Answer (score 1):

If the concurrent threads change only the data in the buffer, you should not get any AV by copying from/to the buffer.

If the concurrent threads change the pointer to the buffer or the variable containing the size of the buffer (number of bytes or elements), you can get an AV easily from copying to/from the buffer using these pointer and size variables. Here you're entering the land of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small possibility. If the write to m_srcPtr isn't atomic, or the other thread is writing to one of the other members and you haven't told us about it (m_nDataSize sounds like a likely thing for instance).

If the write to m_srcPtr isn't atomic, depending on your architecture, you could temporarily have an invalid pointer between the 2 writes to the pointer. If m_nDataSize is updated at "the same time" as m_srcPtr, you have plenty of opportunity for bad things to happen.

Note this is highly architecture dependant.